# Can "rebuild" smart search indexes in Kentico 9 cause any outage to the site?

Tags: indexing, kentico

Our medium size website  (Kentico 9) does not show search results for a new page added. Index status indicates that a rebuild is required. Does anyone know if rebuilding the smart search indexes may cause an outage to the site? The same functionality in Dev and UAT environments is working fine and does not require a rebuild.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKVPe.jpg)

Comment: Please ensure that the `IIS APPPOOL\MyApplicationAppPool` have write permission on `/App_Data/Modules/SmartSearch/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

It very well could depending on your environment.  If your index is very large and you have a lot of traffic, the rebuild process could cause the site to come to a halt because of resource availability.  You may post some more information on your environment to make that determination.

YOu can also check the Kentico event log to see what errors are being written there, if any.  There could also be .lock files in the /App_Data/Modules/SmartSearch/ folder.  Those can cause the index to continue to attempt to rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Brenden. Our event log has an exception that says: Message: Index locked for write: CMS.Search.Lucene3.SearchLock and Exception type: Lucene.Net.Store.LockObtainFailedException. Does this mean we have to delete .lock files in the /App_Data/Modules/SmartSearch/ folder?

Comment: Yes, delete that .lock file in the directory it is specifying.

Comment: Thanks, Brenden for your help with this. The rebuild did not cause any outages in this case :) but it was worth preparing for it in case it did.:)